# Program to manipulate Samba shares (net.exe equivalent)

Tags: linux, command-line, networking, windows, samba

Is there an equivalent to the NET.exe suite for linux systems with which I can do net view queries for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Samba ships a [`net`](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/net.8.html) executable itself. From the man page:

> The Samba net utility is meant to work just like the net utility
>   available for windows and DOS.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found is `smbtree` as an equivalent for `NET VIEW`.